# Calculating error on manually chosen estimated fit

Tags: statistics, data

I understand that this should be basic knowledge, but despite searching all over the internet, I could not pinpoint the answer to this.

Suppose I have data, and it can be linearised to a basic y=mx+c formula, but the data significantly gets noisier along with x, and eventually breaks down due to systematic error.

Using Python's SciPy curve_fit, or Excel's LINEST functions will either take the data as a whole, and return a bad estimate due to the data breaking down, or if I isolate the good segment of the data, it will only return error on the gradient and intercept parameters relative to that data alone.

**(tl;dr)**
So how would I go about using the fitted parameters for a segment of the data, and getting their errors relative to the entire data set? (Given that individual datapoints do not have known associated errors to them)

Would it be appropriate to calculate errors for both the segment, and the entire dataset, and then quote the segment estimate with errors going to the upper bound of entire datasets errors?

i.e.

```
param_error = max(
            abs( entire_set_params - segment_set_params ) + entire_set_error,
            abs( entire_set_params - segment_set_params ) - entire_set_error
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would just write a quick script that calculates $m$ and $b$ over a finite data set and then calculates the errors over a second domain. The formulas are easily found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) and can be implemented in python in 1-2 lines of code. You can even do it very quickly in Excel using the LINEST function to get the slope / intercept and then implement a simple residual-sum-of-squares formula to calculate the error.

I know that's not exactly what you're looking for, but in my experience, trying to force SciPy to do exactly what you want takes longer than writing your own code.

Answer (score 0):

> the good segment of the data, … Given that individual datapoints do not have known associated errors to them

These two statements are contradictory. You cannot consistently both believe that the individual datapoints do not have associated uncertainty and also believe that there is a good segment of data.

In the NIST’s guidelines for evaluating uncertainty ( https://emtoolbox.nist.gov/Publications/NISTTechnicalNote1297s.pdf ) there are two general types of uncertainty: those that are evaluated through statistical means and those that are evaluated through other means.

> the data significantly gets noisier along with x, and eventually breaks down due to systematic error

From this statement it sounds like your concern is that your uncertainty is primarily the non-statistical type. It also appears that you have some estimate of the uncertainty. As the non-statistical uncertainty is strongly varying you need to estimate it for each data point. All sources of uncertainty should be combined into a standard uncertainty for each point.

Then you can use the inverse square of each sample’s standard uncertainty as the weighting factor in a weighted least squares regression. This will use the data, but appropriately discount the uncertain data.